# Using packages with Maven

Tags: java, maven

For all Java projects I have participated in so far I have written build scripts using bash `javac` and `java`. However for my latest project I thought I would dive into Maven.

Whenever I compile my project I am getting compilation errors because a package doesn't exist. I have no external dependencies, but I do have sub packages within my application.

Example structure:

```
src/
    main/
        com/
            mycompany/
                /application
                    /package1
                        MyClass.java
                    /package2
                        MyClass2.java
                    App.java
    test/
pom.xml
```

**Example Classes:

MyClass.java**

```
package com.mycompany.application.package1;
public class MyClass{

    private MyClass(){}

}
```

**App.java**

```
package com.mycompany.application;
import com.mycompany.application.package1.MyClass;
public class App{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }
}
```

- Do I have to somehow define the sub packages within my pom.xml?
- If not, why would maven give me a build error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Maven, you need to standardize your project structure. You just have src/main/, you should have it like src/main/java/

Maven by default will look all the java source/package within src/main/java folder.

See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) for details about project structure.

Answer (score 2):

You should move your packages and classes to `src/main/java`, that is the root folder of packages in maven.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported your project in eclipse, please check your project's .classpath file have the following entry.

```html
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java"> 
  <attributes>
    <attribute name="optional" value="true"/> 
    <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
  </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Sometimes you need check .classpath file. This extra check has worked for me.

And are you executing maven commands from command line? If you executing - 'mvn clean install' like command from command prompt, ideally you should not get an error for the above mentioned directory structure without any changes.